# concatenate strings using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am reading some strings from a batch file and trying to append them all, separated by a space. Here is the code

```
for /F %%x in (C:\dir_1\deploy_build\apps.properties) do (
            set warFiles=%%x%warFiles%
        )
echo %warFiles%
```

if the content of the properties file is

```
sz1056
warFile1
warFile2
```

the output I am getting is `warFile2`
but the output that i am expecting is `sz1056 warFile1 warFile2` 
How can I do this?

Comment: You need delayed variable substitution here, else `%%x%warFiles%` uses the current value of `x` and the old (from before the loop started) value of `warFiles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%x in (C:\dir_1\deploy_build\apps.properties) do (
            set "warFiles=%%x !warFiles!"
        )
echo %warFiles%
```

Comment: its working but I am not getting the expected output yet, this is the output I am getting
`warFile2 warFile1 sz1056 warFile2warFile2`

Comment: @viveksinghggits and is the issue now?

Comment: my bad, the output is correct but the sequence is not. I am expecting `sz1056 warFile1 warFile2` but getting `warFile2 warFile1 sz1056` as output.

Comment: @viveksinghggits because I used your logic. change the set line to `set "warFiles=!warFiles! %%x"`